# XML shredding using nodes() method

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xpath, xquery

I'm having trouble shredding this xml in sql server due to the different levels of nodes in the xml. How can I achieve this in single query.

I have my XML IN following format:

```
<abc>
<item>
<Customer id="12345" age="26">
<NAME>Alex</NAME>
</customer>
</item>
</abc>
```

I tried following query that is giving me customer ID, but I also want name column besides that.

```
SELECT doc.col.value('@id','INT')
FROM @xml.nodes('/abc/item/customer') doc(col)
```

Current output:

```
CustomerID
----------
12345
```

Desired output:

```
CustomerID   Name
----------   -------
  12345      Alex
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it like this

```
DECLARE @xml XML=
N'<abc>
<item>
<customer id="12345" age="26">
<NAME>Alex</NAME>
</customer>
</item>
</abc>';

SELECT doc.col.value('@id','INT') AS ID
      ,doc.col.value('(NAME/text())[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS Name
FROM @xml.nodes('/abc/item/customer') doc(col);
```

Some explanation:

- XML is strictly case sensitive. You have mixed `Customer` and `customer`...
- It helps a lot to look at the XML with correct indentation:

You can see that `<NAME>` is below `<customer>`

```
<abc>
  <item>
    <customer id="12345" age="26">
      <NAME>Alex</NAME>
    </customer>
  </item>
</abc>
```

As your `.nodes()` goes down to `<customer>` this is your *current node*. The attribute `@id` is sitting directly there. The `text()` within `<NAME>` is to be continued from there...